# Iterating through the RowPacketData ( result return from mysql query in node js)

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, api, loops

Case is that I have code to get Product name and Image path from MySQL, so I get RowPacketData in return of query which is like :

```
[ RowDataPacket {
    Id: 1,
    Heading: 'Banner 1',
    Banner_Description: 'This is Banner 1 Description',
    Image_Name: '1596019684532_command3.png' },
  RowDataPacket {
    Id: 2,
    Heading: 'Banner 2',
    Banner_Description: 'This is Banner 1 Description',
    Image_Name: '1596019684538_command4.png' } ]
```

Now I want to append the 'Image_Name' to something like 'var/www/html/Image_Name' and send it to front end. What is best approach to implement this logic for each Image_Name.
Note : I don't want to go in loops.

Comment: You "don't want to go in loops"? Please [edit] your question to explain your restriction. Programmers generally use  loops to process arrays of data.

Comment: Why don't you prepend the path in the select statement? like select "/var/path" + table.image from table? It Send unnecessary data, but I don't see else how you can avoid loops(could be solved with recursion, but in this case it would be just strange)

Answer (score 0):

Presumably you want to send a JSON array to your front end. So you need some code to prepend the path to each `Image_Name` element.  Maybe something like this will work, given your array is in `input`.

```
function prependPath (input, path = 'var/www/html/') {
  for (let i=0; i<input.length; i++) {
    const item = input[i]
    item.Image_Name = path + item.Image_Name
  }
  return input
```

Or you could do this to be a bit more concise.

```
function prependPath (input, path = 'var/www/html/') {
  input.forEach (item => item.Image_Name = path + item.Image_Name)
  }
  return input
}
```

Then call the function with something like `res.json(prependPath (input))` (if you're using Express).